# Make the bootstrap carousel non-responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

My ui-bootstarp carousel ([here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)) is inside a [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I need to make the carousel non-responsive, so it wont get smaller in a smaller screen and the flexbox will react normally and its items will go one underneath each other.

Check the image to help you.

How do I make the carousel non-responsive?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
.owl-item{
float:none !important;
}
```

Don't know if it works

Comment: Okay, can you send me your HTML structure?